# JAVA Array of values need to store in multiple fields based on size

Tags: java, arrays

I am Trying to split this string into array format and trying to store in the field name1,name2.. based on the size of the values and the name filed must have only 26 characters.

> Name:
>   Bommiraj Sitaramanjaneyulu Rajasekhara Srinivasulu Laxminarayana Siva
>   Venkata Sai

**Expected Result:**  name1=  Bommiraj Sitaramanjaneyulu ,name2=Rajasekhara srinivasulu,name3=Laxminarayana Siva Venkata,name4=sai,name5="".

**Actual result:** name field 1:Bommiraju Rajasekhara Siva,name field 2:Venkata Sai

```
String Testname=nameFormat("    Bommiraj     Sitaramanjaneyulu Rajasekhara   Srinivasulu Laxminarayana Siva  Venkata  Sai ");   

String formatedName=name.trim().replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");

    String[] splitedName = formatedName.split("\\s+");

    String name1="";
    String name2="";
    String name3="";
    String name4="";
    String name5="";
    for (String string : splitedName) {
        if (name1.length()==0) {
            name1+=string;
        }else if (name1.length()>0 && name1.length()<26){
            if (string.length()+name1.length()<26) {
                name1+=" "+string;
            }            
        }else if (name2.length()==0) {
            name2+=string;
        }else if (name2.length()>0 && name2.length()<26) {
            if (string.length()+name2.length()<26) {
                name2+=" "+string;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear how you decide where a name ends and another name begins.

Comment: `Bommiraju Sitaramanjaneyulu` is 27 characters long so if the name can't have more than 26 characters like you say, your expected result is incorrect. Even if it were 26 characters long, your code is wrong because it checks whether it is *smaller than* 26 characters long, which means: at most **25** characters.

Comment: Ya sorry it's my spelling mistake name is Bommiraj Sitaramanjaneyulu

Comment: I have made change would you help to solve this @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 0):

If you count up the size of the first name, Bommiraju Sitaramanjaneyulu, there are 26 characters and a space. Your `if` statements are `<26` so will only work up to 25 characters without whitespace.

More generally, I would recommend storing the names as a `String[]` and tracking where you are up to. In your current code, a name might go to string2, but a shorter, later name can go to string1, which I assume is not what you wish to do. What I would recommend, depending on your exact needs, would be to start on `string[0]`, and fill it up until the current string doesn't fit, then move onto `string[1]` and fill that up, etc.

Comment: basically, i am new to JAVA, I need that spaces and the string are not static its dynamic and it could be longer too.i'll like to iterate the string to have the result like I expected is there is any way to do like that

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're wanting to do (a bit late here - I might not be reading as well), but I can mention at this stage that Strings in Java are dynamic. The String[] stores pointers to the Strings they contain, but the Strings pointed to can be any size you like, as they are objects and not char arrays. Is this what you were meaning? As far as iterating over a String goes... using a for loop (max being string.length - 1) and accessing character by character using charAt(i) would be my suggestion.